# Specify holes in Triangle library

Tags: c++, triangulation

I tried to use [Triangle library](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) to tessellate polygons with holes. The tessellated triangles will be rendered by OpenGL.
 My polygon has one exterior ring and multiple interior rings. All I have is the x, y coordinates of all the rings. In order to tessellate with Triangle lib, I have to pass holes list and number of holes to Triangle lib to its triangulateio structure member: `holelist` and `numberofholes`

```
struct triangulateio {
  REAL *pointlist;                                               /* In / out */
  REAL *pointattributelist;                                      /* In / out */
  int *pointmarkerlist;                                          /* In / out */
  int numberofpoints;                                            /* In / out */
  int numberofpointattributes;                                   /* In / out */

  int *trianglelist;                                             /* In / out */
  REAL *triangleattributelist;                                   /* In / out */
  REAL *trianglearealist;                                         /* In only */
  int *neighborlist;                                             /* Out only */
  int numberoftriangles;                                         /* In / out */
  int numberofcorners;                                           /* In / out */
  int numberoftriangleattributes;                                /* In / out */

  int *segmentlist;                                              /* In / out */
  int *segmentmarkerlist;                                        /* In / out */
  int numberofsegments;                                          /* In / out */

  REAL *holelist;                        /* In / pointer to array copied out */
  int numberofholes;                                      /* In / copied out */

  REAL *regionlist;                      /* In / pointer to array copied out */
  int numberofregions;                                    /* In / copied out */

  int *edgelist;                                                 /* Out only */
  int *edgemarkerlist;            /* Not used with Voronoi diagram; out only */
  REAL *normlist;                /* Used only with Voronoi diagram; out only */
  int numberofedges;                                             /* Out only */
};
```

The holes are represented by the coordinate of one point inside the hole. My question is: Can I do the tessellation without specifying the holes(use just the internal rings)? OR if I have to list the holes, how can I find one point inside the holes fast? The process here is time critical.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do the tessellation without specifying the holes. 
A possible way to find a point inside a hole is to triangulate it as if it were a simple ring (no holes in it) and take e.g. the center of mass of one of the output triangles. I hope it helped.